# Capturing virtual screen (all monitors)

Tags: c#, virtual, screenshot

I am trying to get a screenshot of the whole virtual screen. This means, an image of not just the primary screen, but every screen connected to the computer.

Is there a way to do that? I tried using this, but it didn't work:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
this.Size = new Size(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);
```

Comment: What does exactly not work? Are you getting some kind of exception?

Comment: it only captures primary screen...

Comment: didnt know about "virtualscreen", thanks dude

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1kt6f9%28VS.80%29.aspx) says: `Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Size)`: Performs a bit-block transfer of the color data, corresponding to a **rectangle** of pixels, from the screen to the drawing surface of the Graphics." But the virtual screen is not necessarily a rectangle: imagine two monitors with 1920x1200 and 1280x1024 resolutions. So what you need to do is create a bitmap like you do, then enumerate your monitors and execute `CopyFromScreen()` for each of them.

**Edit:** If, for instance, you have two monitors, the one having 1280x1024 resolution standing on the **left** of 1920x1200 one, then the coordinates of the former would be (-1280,0) - (0, 1024). Therefore you need to execute `memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(-1280, 0, 0, 0, s);` where s is the `Size(1280,1024)`. For the second one you need to call `memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, *1280*, 0, s);` and s would be the `Size(1920, 1200)`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Igor is right, passing 0, 0 for the SourceX/Y arguments isn't correct.  Iterate the Screen instances in the `Screen.AllScreens` property to find the bounding rectangle.  Beware that `CopyFromScreen()` has a bug, it cannot capture layered windows (the kind that has `TransparencyKey` or `Opacity` set).  Check my answer in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/474450b9-e260-4369-9efb-0d57a5b2e06d/) for a workaround.

Beware that capturing the entire desktop isn't always practical, you'll get lots of black when the screens are not arranged in a perfect rectangle and an `OutOfMemory` exception is not uncommon on a 32-bit machine with high resolution displays.

Comment: If the lots of black works for <kbd>Print Scrn</kbd>, i assume it should be good enough for OP.

Comment: Hmm, the black of course only shows up on his customer's machine.

Answer (score 2):

Like Igor and Hans have said, you have to indicate the source coordinate :

```
Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(
    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, 
    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height, 
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics screenGraph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);

screenGraph.CopyFromScreen(
    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X, 
    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y, 
    0, 
    0, 
    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size, 
    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```