# Wrote a C# application that takes a screencapture using SendKeys.SendWait("{PRTSC}")

Tags: c#

I wrote a C# application that takes a screencapture using `SendKeys.SendWait("{PRTSC}")`.  This does not always work.   The reason I went down this route as opposed to using the functions such as copyScreenImage is because some people might have multiple screens and I could not figure out if the screen was one above the other or side by side.  This matters if you want to take a screenshot of everything.   Any thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500175/capturing-virtual-screen-all-monitors should get you started.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Where and when are you calling SendKeys? On a button press? On a timer? Everytime someone googles "snooki"?

Comment: The {PRTSC} key has been documented as "reserved" for a long time.  Which typically means that they know it is not reliable.

Comment: We have a customer helpdesk portal that I added screenshot capability.  Basically, it just takes a screenshot (by sending sendkeys.send("{PRTSC}") and then copying it to the clipboard and saving it to a file which gets uploaded.