# CopyFromScreen with virtual screen

Tags: c#, .net

I need to take screenshot of my app (inside app itself ofc), and i can use `CopyFromScreen` function for this. But it should be adapted to several monitors as well.
So, how `CopyFromScreen` works with virtual screen? And how can i get position of my app window on virtual screen?

Primary question is actually second one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing virtual screen (all monitors)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500175/capturing-virtual-screen-all-monitors)

Comment: @Sinatr, please, consider difference between "capturing **whole** virtual screen" and "capturing **application window** on virtual screen". Neither is my own question answered there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, `Application.Current.MainWindow` coordinate parameters work just fine with virtual screen